# Maven Dependency for PDI(Pentaho Kettle) Jar files

Tags: maven, pentaho, kettle

I have written Java code to execute my transformation and Jobs and I have manually added all the Jar files present in the data-integration/lib folder to my class path and evrything is working fine.

Now I want to mavenize my project and looking for XML which specifies the groupid and artifact Id for each of the jar that are present in lib directory of data-integration. I found the [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/pentaho-kettle) here but they does not include all the dependencies.

PDI Version - 5.0.1 Stable

Answer (score 5):

Here the lastest I use:

```
<properties>
    <pentaho-kettle.version>5.4.1.8-209</pentaho-kettle.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>pentaho-releases</id>
        <url>http://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-kettle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-vfs</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-vfs</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-kettle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-ui-swt</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-kettle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libformula</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-kettle.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
        <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
        <version>1.7R5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

If using the Json Output step you'll also need this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And to call REST services you'll need this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonpath</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Even with my edits, this doesn't work 100% reliably. User Defined Java Step is broken. So I started a project in github to collect additional fixes - https://github.com/atramos/PDI-Kettle-Tomcat-Spring-Maven-Demo

Answer (score 1):

I found this link :

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?131872-Maven-Dependencies-for-Pentaho-DataIntegration

Hope it helps :)

---

*[Edited to modify my answer]*

I have tried to mavenize my plugin development. Please check out this blog:
https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/12/29/maven-dependencies-for-building-pentaho-di-kettle-plugins/

I have used the pom.xml as explained in the blog link. I have developed for pentaho version : 5.0.0.1. Try using this and check whether it resolves your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I simply use this and it's **ok** for me:

```
    <repository>
        <id>pentaho-repo</id>
        <url>http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/</url>
    </repository>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the Gradle version:

```
 maven {
        url 'https://public.nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to add this two dependencies to work fine in 6.1.x version

```
   <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
                <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
     </dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>simple-jndi</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-jndi</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.4</version>
</dependency>
```